# Making image map editable

Tags: php

I Am using an image map to identify faces in a group photo using the title attribute:

 etc

Can I store the coords and title data in a database and reconstruct the image map?
I've tried (and failed) with this code:

```
    <p><img src="1963.jpg" width="5344" height="1152" border="0" usemap="#Map">
  <map name="Map">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$passwd,$dbase);    

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `t1963`");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows>0){
        while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) ){
            $id=$rows['id'];
            $coords=$rows['coords'];
            $title=$rows['title'];
            $chr=chr(034);
  $immap = "<area shape=".$chr."circle".$chr." coords=".$coords." href=".$chr."#".$chr." title=".$id." - ".$title.">";
  echo "$immap";
  echo "<br>";
  }
  }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>

  </map>
</p>
```

Comment: Post the interpreted source code. And also that `<br>` should not be a descendant of `<map>`

Answer (score 0):

At first glance (and without seeing the interpreted source) the biggest problem is that some of your area attribute values are not quoted. Your interpreted source would not have quotes around `coords` or `title` attributes for each `area`.  Also you can simplify how you're constructing your `$immap` variable.  See example:

**Change:**

```
$immap = "<area shape=".$chr."circle".$chr." coords=".$coords." href=".$chr."#".$chr." title=".$id." - ".$title.">";
```

**to:**

```
$immap = "<area shape='circle' coords='$coords' href='#' title='$id - $title'>";
```

Also remove the `<br>`. It should not be a descendant of `<map>`.  If you're just looking to put each `<area>` on a new line in your source, then use `\n`:

```
$echo $immap\n;
```

Comment: It’s displayed in an iframe:
See
http://www.dunstableschool.co.uk/photos/panoramas/1963/1963frame.htm
It always displays photo from top left. Can it be made to default to bottom center?

Comment: you should be able to position it however you wish with CSS.